# What is a particle in loop-quantum-gravity?

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-gravity, loop-quantum-gravity

What exactly is the underlying mathematical structure of e.g. an electron in Loop-quantum-gravity? And is there a simple way to get the quantum mechanical limit so that one can see how the wave function of a particle emerges from this underlying mathematical structure describing a particle in Loop-quantum-gravity.

Comment: I don't think that LQG has an alternative description to particles. It is a quantum theory of graivty. That is, it attempts to reconcile gravity with the standard model of particle physics.

Comment: @josephh LQG doesn’t reconcile anything with the Standard Model, it attempts to reconcile General Relativity with Quantum Mechanics.

Comment: Assume for a second that LQG in its final form was accepted as a valid theory for quantum gravity. Do you think that it should be mathematically consistent with the SM? If not why? If so, then your point is meaningless.

Comment: @josephh Quantum Gravity means a quantum-mechanical theory that gives General Relativity in the classical limit. There is no requirement that the Standard Model should follow. What you're talking about is a Theory of Everything (ToE), which must unify gravity with the Standard Model forces. LQG doesn't have the Standard Model particle content, it is a theory of pure gravity. Hence, it is a Quantum Gravity candidate, but not a ToE candidate (perhaps LQG coupled to other matter fields is a ToE candidate).